# MVC3 JQuery Tabs

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, jquery-ui, jquery

I am trying to create a page with three tabs containing 3 partial views. 
Main View that hosts the tabs.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(function () {
    $("#tabs").tabs();
});
</script>
<div id="tabs" style="display:inline; float:inherit">
<ul>
    <li>@Ajax.ActionLink("Tab name1","ActionMethod1","ControllerName",new      AjaxOptions{UpdateTargetId="div1"})</li>
    <li>@Ajax.ActionLink("Tab name2","ActionMethod2","ControllerName",new AjaxOptions{UpdateTargetId="div2"})</li>
<li>@Ajax.ActionLink("Tab name3","ActionMethod3","ControllerName",new AjaxOptions{UpdateTargetId="div3"})</li>
</ul>
</div>
<div id=div1></div>
<div id=div2></div>
<div id=div3></div>
```

I have created next button in tab1 and tab2 and submit button in tab3.

Please give the code to open tab2 from tab1 on button(next) click. and where to put this code. Is it in this main view or the partial views?

Comment: http://mattgemmell.com/2008/12/08/what-have-you-tried/

Comment: I have created the tabbed view. Trying to figure out how to switch from one tab to another and also submit the forms(tab1 and tab2) in the submit button of tab3.

Comment: Put a button in tab 1.
Write jQuery to open tab 2 when clicked.
Put a button in tab 2 and do the same.
Then put your submit button in tab 3.
You should be holding all of the data in a view model.
On submit, send that viewModel to the controller.

If you want a detailed answer you'll have to post a more specific question with a specific problem, and code that illustrates it.

(BTW, validation's likely to be a PITA splitting a single form into multiple partials.)

Comment: I have created next button in tab1 and tab2 and submit button in tab3.

Please give the code to open tab2 from tab1 on button(next) click. and where to put this code. Is it in this main view or the partial views?

Answer (score 0):

Addressing the more specific question from your comment

To open tab 2 from a button click in tab 1:

Html (Standard markup for [jQuery tabs](http://jqueryui.com/tabs/)):

```
<div id="tabs">
        <ul>
            <li><a id="tab1" href="#tabs-1">Tab One</a></li>
            <li><a id="tab2" href="#tabs-2">Tab Two</a></li>
            <li><a id="tab3" href="#tabs-3">Tab Three</a></li>
        </ul>
   <div id="tabs-1>
         <button type="button" id="GotoTab2">Next</button>
   </div>
   <div id="tabs-2">
         <!-- some content -->
   </div>
```

jQuery

```
$(function () {
        $("#tabs").tabs(); 
        $('#GotoTab2').click(function () {
           $('#tab2').click();
        });
    });
```